# how to change .ear file name in JDeveloper?

Tags: web-services, jdeveloper

I'm trying to minimize the default name of the ear file in JDeveloper but it is not reflecting in project and after changing the name when i try to redeploy the project it gets failed. please help me to sort out this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the name of the app in the application properties->Deploy section.